# Linq query for view returns no elements

Tags: json, entity-framework, sql-view

Currently, I am trying to populate additional values within the same ViewModel. So what happens is my viewmodel is populated initially via this JsonResult method.

```
public virtual JsonResult GetInstitutionContacts(Guid? provideruid)
{
    return Json(new { ContactViewModel = _repository.GetContactsByProviderUid(provideruid) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The parameter value is set when a user makes a selection from a dropdown list. The repository that my JsonResult method utilizes looks like this:

```
    public IQueryable<ContactViewModel> GetContactsByProviderUid(Guid? provideruid)
    {
        var q = from r in Context.vw_DistrictContacts.Where(p => p.ProviderUid == provideruid && p.School == AdminBuilding)
                select new ContactViewModel
                {
                    FamilyName = r.GivenNames.ToUpper(),
                    GivenName = r.FamilyNames.ToUpper(),
                    CourtesyTitle = r.Title,
                    ContactId = r.PersonUid
                };
        return q.Distinct();
    }
```

The table view within my context (Context.vw_DistrictContacts) returns those exact fields(FamilyName, GiveName...). The issue occurs when the user then selects another value.
The dropdown selection then triggers this controller method:

```
        public virtual JsonResult GetSchoolContacts(Guid provideruid)
        {
            return Json(new { ContactViewModel = _repository.GetContacts(provideruid) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

This is what the repository method looks like:

```
   public List<ContactViewModel> GetContacts(Guid? providerUid)
    {
        var q = from r in Context.vw_PersonToSdeUsers.Where(p => p.ProviderUid == providerUid)
                select new ContactViewModel
                {
                    SchoolName = r.SchoolName,
                    ContactId = r.PersonUid,
                    PersonUid = r.PersonUid,
                    FamilyName = r.GivenNames.ToUpper(),
                    GivenName = r.FamilyNames.ToUpper(),
                    SdeUserEmail = r.SdeUserEmail,
                    CourtesyTitle = r.ProgramDescription
                };
        return q.ToList();
    }
```

Again the table view (Context.vw_PersonToSdeUsers) returns exactly what is expected. But the return value "q.ToList()" is null. I believe the issue is the fact that I am already consuming ContactViewModel. Also I have ran the select statement for the table view and it returns as expected. I have also ran the provider filter and again it returns as expected.

Comment: I think you should add Entity tag. It is`t a Repository issue. It looks like Entity Framework issue. We need to know how you work with Context and more things about your Entity implementation.

Comment: Thanks I have added an entity tag will also add a linq to sql tag since that is what I am using for my ORM. I have solved the issue but I feel it was a bit hack. What I currently have implemented is another model that defines the expected properties and from here I populate it with the GetContacts() method and everything works as expected. Again it feels a bit hack.

Comment: Something is wrong. `q.ToList()` can't be null.  It's impossible.  q will always contain an `IQueryable`, and `q.ToList()` will always return a list, which may or may not be Empty (0 elements).  Is there any code here you're not showing us?

Comment: @MystereMan My apologies q.ToList() returns "enumeration yielded no results" you are right null is not being returned. But the code listed is everything. Besides the view which is irrelevant.

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC, view models, or repositories... its entirely an entity framework issue relating to querying against sql views.

Comment: Have you verified that you are in fact passing valid data into the method by setting a breakpoint on your query and checking the parameters?

Comment: Yes I have verified. As I have stated above the view returns valid data and when I run this method first it works as it should. But, the use case will be when a user selects the first dropdown it will invoke GetInstitutionContacts(Guid? provideruid) from here the next drop down will invoke the method GetSchoolContacts(Guid provideruid). The fail is it does not repopulate my viewmodel (ContactViewModel). I have worked through this issue by creating another model but I feel this is hack...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks I have added an entity tag will also add a linq to sql tag since that is what I am using for my ORM. I have solved the issue but I feel it was a bit hack. What I currently have implemented is another model that defines the expected properties and from here I populate it with the GetContacts() method and everything works as expected. Again it feels a bit hack.